# How do I create a scrolling menu using HTML or CSS code?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm trying to recreate a menu much like the one seen on [Beyonce's Tumblr page](http://iam.beyonce.com/). What html/css tags do I use to create that effect? I'm referring to the menu that slides over when clicking on the arrow.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to achieve such an effect. If you want to emulate that specific effect, why not look at the source?

Comment: It's hard not to have a dig at you here for your lack of effort but I'll try. In order to get help here on stackoverflow you should first attempt to make it happen yourself and if you can't quite get it working come back here, show your code and ask for some help from the community.

Comment: I already looked at the source and tried to copy it, but when I put it into my website, it wasn't keeping the same function and a matter of fact, got rid of the content behind it... So I did attempt to make it happen, just didn't put the code in. I'm new here.

Answer (score 1):

You want to read [this article](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/tutorials/css3-menu-with-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadows) for create a basic menu in CSS3/HTML , in the website, you can generate a menu with HTML/CSS... BUt for more effects, you can use Javascript library [sample : [JqueryUI demo effects]](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example to get you started.

HTML

```
​<div id="menu">
    Hello world!
    <div class="tab">&gt;</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS

```
​#menu {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: -600px;
    top: 50px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.tab {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
    top: 0;
    color: #FFF:
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab").toggle(function() { 
        $('#menu').animate({ left: '0' }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $('#menu').animate({ left: '-600' }, 500);
    });​
});
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yW8Gb/)
​

Comment: I tried plugging this in but still didn't work on my blog. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong spot?

Comment: Still really new to this site, not sure where to copy and paste the source on here, but you can view the source at http://actuallyandy.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation. You need to insert the following in different sections:

***Head Section:***

```
<style>
<!--
#slidemenubar, #slidemenubar2{
position:absolute;
border:1.5px solid black;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
layer-background-color:#F2F2F2;
font:bold 12px Verdana;
line-height:20px;
}
-->
</style>
```

***Body Section***

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

var slidemenu_width='160px' //specify width of menu (in pixels)
var slidemenu_reveal='12px' //specify amount that menu should protrude initially
var slidemenu_top='170px'   //specify vertical offset of menu on page

var ns4=document.layers?1:0
var ie4=document.all
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all?1:0

if (ie4||ns6)
document.write('<div id="slidemenubar2" style="left:'+((parseInt(slidemenu_width)-    parseInt(slidemenu_reveal))*-1)+'px; top:'+slidemenu_top+'; width:'+slidemenu_width+'"     onMouseover="pull()" onMouseout="draw()">')
else if (ns4){
document.write('<style>\n#slidemenubar{\nwidth:'+slidemenu_width+';}\n<\/style>\n')
document.write('<layer id="slidemenubar" left=0 top='+slidemenu_top+'     width='+slidemenu_width+' onMouseover="pull()" onMouseout="draw()" visibility=hide>')
}

var sitems=new Array()

///////////Edit below/////////////////////////////////

//siteitems[x]=["Item Text", "Optional URL associated with text"]

sitems[0]=["<big><font face='Arial'>Site Menu</font></big>", ""]
sitems[1]=["Link 1", "http://www.google.com/"]
sitems[2]=["Link 2", "http://www.link2.com/"]
sitems[3]=["Link 3", "http://www.link3.com/"]
sitems[4]=["Link 4", "http://www.link4.com/"]
sitems[5]=["Link 5", "http://www.link5.com/"]
sitems[6]=["Link 6", "http://www.link6.com/"]
sitems[7]=["Link 7", "http://www.link7.com/"]

//If you want the links to load in another frame/window, specify name of target (ie:     target="_new")
var target=""

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (ie4||ns4||ns6){
for (i=0;i<sitems.length;i++){
if (sitems[i][1])
document.write('<a href="'+sitems[i][1]+'" target="'+target+'">')
document.write(sitems[i][0])
if (sitems[i][1])
document.write('</a>')
document.write('<br>\n')
}
}

function regenerate(){
window.location.reload()
}
function regenerate2(){
if (ns4){
document.slidemenubar.left=((parseInt(slidemenu_width)-parseInt(slidemenu_reveal))*-1)
document.slidemenubar.visibility="show"
setTimeout("window.onresize=regenerate",400)
}
}
window.onload=regenerate2

rightboundary=0
leftboundary=(parseInt(slidemenu_width)-parseInt(slidemenu_reveal))*-1

if (ie4||ns6){
document.write('</div>')
themenu=(ns6)? document.getElementById("slidemenubar2").style :     document.all.slidemenubar2.style
}
else if (ns4){
document.write('</layer>')
themenu=document.layers.slidemenubar
}

function pull(){
if (window.drawit)
clearInterval(drawit)
pullit=setInterval("pullengine()",10)
}
function draw(){
clearInterval(pullit)
drawit=setInterval("drawengine()",10)
}
function pullengine(){
if ((ie4||ns6)&&parseInt(themenu.left)<rightboundary)
themenu.left=parseInt(themenu.left)+10+"px"
else if(ns4&&themenu.left<rightboundary)
themenu.left+=10
else if (window.pullit){
themenu.left=0
clearInterval(pullit)
}
}

function drawengine(){
if ((ie4||ns6)&&parseInt(themenu.left)>leftboundary)
themenu.left=parseInt(themenu.left)-10+"px"
else if(ns4&&themenu.left>leftboundary)
themenu.left-=10
else if (window.drawit){
themenu.left=leftboundary
clearInterval(drawit)
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: okay @CamelUno,so I used this code and put it in, however, when I made adjustments to the values to make the menu bigger, the menu disappeared from my page completely. I out the head section right after <head> and the body section right after <body>

Comment: I'm trying to put my whole source in to show you, but it's not letting me